# How to find the color profile/space used by a photo?

Tags: metadata, color-management

Some of my photos look different because I was not careful with saving with or without color profile. Now I would like to be able to find out what color profile is used by an image. Is there a simple tool to see this? Hopefully a command line one? I'll try to pay attention next time!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) is a command-line utility that does exactly what you're after. Check out the [ICC profile documentation](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/TagNames/ICC_Profile.html).

Comment: Good news! I got Exiftool. Bad news! I don't understand the help. Are there examples for getting the color space and profile out?

Comment: I've no idea I'm afraid, Zak, I just happened to know that exiftool ticked your boxes of colour profile + command line. I haven't used it myself.

Comment: @Zak - Just drop photos into the executable, and it will show you the color space as one of the output rows if the image has one defined. If none is defined, I believe it won't output any row for color space.

Comment: @dpollit did't work for me. I have an image with Adobe RGB profile embedded, but `exiv2 -pa | grep -i adobe` shows nothing.

Comment: And it's conveniently hosted on the web here: http://regex.info/exif.cgi

Comment: It seems to be showing only Color Space, not the profile

Comment: `exiftool -icc_profile -b somefile.jpg`

Answer (score 10):

You can use imagemagick's `identify` program for this.

Example:

```
$ identify -verbose example.jpg | grep -A1 Profile-icc 
Profile-icc: 560 bytes
  Adobe RGB (1998)
```

(I could not get this out with the `exiv2` tool mentioned in another answer.)

Comment: The full command is: `magick identify rose.jpg` after you install: https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Comment: For me it just says `"Profile-icc: 940 bytes"` and the next line is unrelated.

Comment: The grep is probably superfluous, unless you are writing a script.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got Adobe Bridge or Lightroom?
Bridge can sort by Colour Profile, but I cannot find a way to do it in Lightroom, though it must exist (if it does in Bridge).
This will only work in Windows or on a Mac though.

Alternatively, in Windows the colour profile is reported as part of the image properties, so it would just be an entry in metadata.
So I would guess it should not be difficult to write a script that queries the metadata for every image, but I am the wrong person to tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

i tricked nikon scan into using prophoto rgb by swapping out the stored adobe rgb profile and renaming prophoto rgb as adobe rgb within nikon scan. was trying to find out how i did it 8 years ago..
having some trouble with posterizing skin tones in the poor underexposed images, but it is for archive so in the future that may become easier...