# Colour spaces accross different monitors

Tags: color-management, srgb

I have a question about colour spaces.

I have taken photos on a digital SLR in RAW, processed them in Adobe Lightroom and then exported them as JPG's with the sRGB profile.

On my home setup with the DELL u2713h (wide gamut monitor), when I open photos using a colour managed application - the JPG's look great, and when I open them in a non-colour managed application they don't - i understand why, and this is all fine.

The problem i am having is after I have uploaded the JPG's to Google Photos and then view them from my work computer which uses the standard run-of-the mill Dell monitors. When viewing at work the colours are over-saturated even when viewed using a colour managed application.

Everything I have been reading suggests this shouldn't be the case as it should be reading sRGB from the photo and displaying normally?

Can anyone help me to understand why this may be? I'm worried all the photos I share are coming out over saturated when viewed by other people.

thanks.

PS - here is an example photo
https://goo.gl/photos/BHecW2AegsEgWBw78

Comment: sRGB is a colour space, not a colour profile. Do your images have embedded ICC profiles?

Comment: @Mick im not sure. How can i find that out?

Comment: There is no option in LR for embedding so i guess whatever it does by default..

Comment: [How to find the color profile/space used by a photo](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15333/how-to-find-the-color-profile-space-used-by-a-photo)

Comment: @Mick it says sRGB..

Comment: Have the monitors at your work been calibrated and profiled? Assuming you have calibrated and profiled your personal monitor, Occam's razor says the others have the saturation turned up too high.

Comment: Do you have an x-rite i1 Display pro for your Dell? You did not mention this. Has it been profiled? sRGB looks slightly washed out in a Dell wide gammut display, so if you correct the color for what you see on the Dell in sRGB, then open on another display, it will look over saturated. I have 3 Dells, and they all have to be calibrated with an x-rite.

Comment: @MichaelClark No i dont think they have been calibrated or profiled. I dont have security privileges to do that. But i can tell you the correct drivers and monitor profiles have been loaded.

Comment: @Gmck no unfortunately i cannot afford an x-rite calibration tool. So it has not been profiled.. Do you really think my monitors could be that far out in terms of calibration??

Comment: Example image url added above.

Comment: @Grant You can afford a 27" wide gamut monitor but not a colorimeter that can be had for as little as $150 or even rented for much less?

Comment: @MichaelClark without getting into specifics yes. if i had known when i bought it then i could have but right now its not in the budget..

Comment: Without calibration, you are not seeing the true color of the images and will have this variation. Dell recommends the x-rite and even sells it as an accessory. It appears on every one of the the Premier Color series monitors. If your video adapter can display 30bit color - it's even more critical that you profile it. I can understand budget issues, but Michael is right, you can rent one for $15 for a day. Pretty cheap to solve such a critical issue in your workflow.

Comment: @Gmck ok thanks. i wasnt aware i could rent one until this post. Ill try and track one down and see if that helps. Thank you.

Comment: Is your home monitor calibrated?

Comment: It will solve your problem for sure. Rent only the i1 Display Pro, not the color munky. The Dell UltraSharp Color Calibration software is a branded version for i1 Pro and does not work with anything else (unless Dell has changed that). You also have to change your display to use CAL1 or CAL2.

Comment: Hi guys please see comment from me at the end of the next answer..

Answer (score 1):

If you edited with a wide-gamut monitor, it is likely that in editing, you have chosen some colors that are 'out of gamut' for standard monitors. Your wide-gamut monitor can display them, but others can not.  You can control for this by changing your monitor profile, using a monitor calibration tool. If you have Photoshop, there is a basic tool built in. You can switch easily in Photoshop by using the 'soft proof' setting. There is also a tool built into MacOS in the Displays setting. Here you can switch Display profile easily. (Sorry, don't remember if Windows has one).

Another issue may be the type of screen you are viewing on. Your main screen is likely a IPS-type display, where the image stays true to color even when viewed off-axis. But if the 'run of the mill' Dell displays are TN, then the color shifts dramatically when viewed off axis. There is really no fix for this, other than getting the colors within the gamut of the display, and within the sRGB color profile. (and viewing in the middle of the display).

Answer (score 0):

The way I am reading it: the images were made with display A and they look fine on display A. They don't look correctly on other display(s).

If that's the case, assuming that the other displays are set to defaults, your display A profile or setting may be the culprit.

Posting an example could be helpful. People here could tell if they see anything wrong. Get [test images](http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/downloadable_1/DL_page.html) or [color checker](http://babelcolor.com/colorchecker.htm) image and display them on your A display to see if they look correct.

Comment: I have edited with a link to one of the affected photos. Can you see anything wrong?

Comment: @Grant the photo looks normal to me. Bit on the saturated side, but normal.

Comment: @MirekE the core issue here is the Dell monitors with Premier Color display sRGB slightly muted compared to non-wide gammut displays, so what happens one will correct it and it looks great on your Dell, but over saturated everywhere else.

Comment: hey guys thanks for all your input. i went ahead and bought an x-rite i1 display pro and have calibrated my monitors using the Dell UltraSharp Color Calibration Solution which seems to be better. In addition, i have also found another piece of software by Dell call the Dell UltraSharp Calibration System which seems to do something different - instead of writing information to the monitor the output is an ICC profile. My question is - do i need to update the monitor as well as create a new profile? or is the monitor update enough...

Answer (score -1):

When I setup a new work space, I take a known image that I have worked with in the past and I adjust the main monitor brightness, contrast and colors.

Then I compare the screen to a printed version, a tablet, and a few new smart phones.

After the main monitor is calibrated, I adjust the other monitors. I usually work with 3 monitors.

I usually only proof my prints/shots with my best monitor (display resolution, colors, and clarity.)

Even with top of the line Intel graphics to run all three monitors, only one monitor represents what most users will typically see. The other two let me know what the image looks like with less than ideal settings.

NOTE: There is a possibility that your operating system in conjunction with your conversion software is writing strangely. I've notice images exported to JPEG from Canon raw on a Windows 10 computer will not show the revisions in thumbnails. Where there is a file reading/writing issue. I also noticed this in Topaz lab exports.

Comment: This answer seems to be off-topic. You are not talking about color management but explain how you try to make a few displays look similar...

Comment: I politely disagree. Grant is looking for a baseline to work consistently and get repeatable results. I defined how to manage output and display colors. Once he knows what other users are looking at, then he can calibrate respective color space/color profiles.